# Is it possible to record audio from app extension in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, ios-app-extension, ios8.3, ios8-share-extension

The [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1872/_index.html) clearly saying that, in iOS8 it is not possible to record audio from app extensions. But the documentary date is `2014-08-14`.

I'm actually developing an extension for iOS 8.3, trying to record audio in that, but not able to achieve the functionality.

Any one tried to record audio from app extension in iOS Latest versions (iOS8.3) ?

or it is not possible to record audio from app extension in latest versions iOS (iOS8.3) ?

I need your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Versions 8.X are bug fixing versions and rarely change something in Framework availability. Also documents that are not correct are marked as archived by Apple

Comment: This documentation repeats that you can't do it, and was last updated in March of this year. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2 As a side note however, segments of this guide are themselves incorrect (and not marked as archived) -- I would take anything it says you *can* do with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'm trying to record audio in an app extension today (in iOS 10). I've seen apps that actually does this but I can't get it do work using the AVAudioEngine. Have you got it to work @Ashok Kumar S?

Comment: I have tried, but it did not work. But there may be other working solutions, but i'm not sure.